# Sliding Puzzle - DFS Issue

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search, adjacency-matrix

I am new to Graph problems and trying to solve the [Leetcode Problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/sliding-puzzle/) using DFS.
My algorithm is basically a brute force DFS where I move the "0" square either left, right, up or down and count the moves each time (I swap the 0 with number in the square that is a valid move). With each move, I check the desired state and save the number of moves in a global variable. I always take the min of the current # of moves and the existing # of moves to always keep track of the least amount of moves.

The issue I am running into is that it never reaches the desired state and always returns Integer.MAX_VALUE (the initialization for the number of moves)

Any guidance or help with the DFS algorithm for this particular problem is greatly appreciated.

```java
public class SlidingPuzzle {
    int moves = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    public int slidingPuzzle(int[][] board) {
        int move  = 0;
        boolean visited[][] = new boolean[board.length][board[0].length];
        for(int i  = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++) {
                if(board[i][j]== 0) {
                    slidingPuzzleHelper(board, move, i, j, visited);
                }
            }
        }
        return moves;
    }
    
    private void slidingPuzzleHelper(int[][]board, int move, int i, int j, boolean visited[][]) {
        printState(board);
        if(isValid(board)) {
            moves = Math.min(moves, move);
            return;
        }
        int temp = -1;
        visited [i][j] = true;
        //up
        if( i + 1 < board.length && i + 1 >= 0 && j>=0 && j < board[0].length && !visited[i + 1][j]) {
            temp = board[i + 1][j];
            board[i][j] = temp;
            board[i + 1][j] = 0;
            slidingPuzzleHelper(board, move + 1, i + 1, j, visited);
            board[i][j] = 0;
            board[i + 1][j] = temp;
            printState(board);
        }
        
        if( i-1  < board.length && i -1  >= 0 &&  j>=0 && j < board[0].length && !visited[i-1][j]) {
            temp = board[i - 1][j];
            board[i][j] = temp;
            board[i - 1][j] = 0;
            slidingPuzzleHelper(board, move + 1, i - 1, j, visited);
            board[i][j] = 0;
            board[i - 1][j] = temp;
            printState(board);
        }
        
        if( j + 1  < board[0].length && j + 1  >= 0 && i>=0 && i < board.length && !visited[i][j + 1]) {
            temp = board[i][j + 1];
            board[i][j] = temp;
            board[i][j + 1] = 0;
            slidingPuzzleHelper(board, move + 1, i, j + 1, visited);
            board[i][j] = 0;
            board[i][j + 1] = temp;
            printState(board);
        }
        
        if( j - 1  < board[0].length && j - 1  >= 0 && i>=0 && i < board.length && !visited[i][j- 1]) {
            temp = board[i][j - 1];
            board[i][j] = temp;
            board[i][j - 1] = 0;
            slidingPuzzleHelper(board, move + 1, i, j - 1, visited);
            board[i][j] = 0;
            board[i][j - 1] = temp;
            printState(board);
        }
        
        visited [i][j] = false;
    }
    
    private boolean isValid(int[][] board) {
        int[][] ans = {{1,2,3},{4,5,0}};
        for(int i  = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            for(int j  = 0; j < board[0].length; j++) {
                if(ans[i][j] != board[i][j]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    private void printState(int[][] board) {
        for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(board[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("************");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] board = {{4,1,3}, {2,0,5}};
        SlidingPuzzle sp = new SlidingPuzzle();
        System.out.println(sp.slidingPuzzle(board));
    }

}
```

Comment: It is returning MAX_VALUE because it never finds a solution.  And it never finds a solution because your algorithm assumes that a valid solution only ever has to visit each cell at most once which is not true.

Comment: @RBarryYoung are you hinting that DFS may not be a suitable algorithm beacuse if I do not keep track its going to give me a stackoverflow error as it will never stop!

Comment: Recursive DFS should work for this problem, it is small enough that stack overflows should not be a problem when implemented correctly.  However, what I am saying about your implementation is that your `visited[][]` criteria for cutting DFS off is incorrect and is cutting it off too soon.

Comment: hmmm ....i still do not see how its cutting off fast. Could you explain further or provide a hint please.

Comment: "*your algorithm assumes that a valid solution only ever has to visit each cell at most once which is not true*"

Comment: Consider the following 5-step solution to your puzzle: starts at 0:`[[4,1,3][2,0,5]`, 1:`[[4,1,3][0,2,5]]`, 2:`[[0,1,3][4,2,5]]`, 3:`[[1,0,3][4,2,5]]`, 4:`[[1,2,3][4,0,5]]`, and finally 5:`[[1,2,3][4,5,0]]`.  Your algorithm would cut-off this search branch at step 4 because the zero had already visited that cell in the initial state.

Comment: So a better approach would be to save the state of the board and check if I have seen that state before and not the cell?

Comment: Yes, that is the standard check for this type of search.

Comment: Thanks @RBarryYoung...you left just enough ambiguity (for lack of a better word) to not give it a way and get the thought process going.

Comment: The task is to _ return the least number of moves required so that the state of the board is solved_ so you need to use **BFS**.

Comment: either DFS or BFS will work for this problem